# Has one association without a belongs to on the associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have as a model

```
Dogs
has_one :cat
```

and have a cat_id in the dog table... then I would like to call `Dog.first.cat`

This doesn't seem to be working for me. Am I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `has_one`, so it's actually the `cats` table that should have the `dog_id`.

In your case, you would use `belongs_to :cat` in the `Dog` model.

Take a look at the doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Is+it+a+belongs_to+or+has_one+association%3F

Answer (score 0):

`Dog belongs_to :cat` 
`Cat has_one :dog`